# Is it possible to automatically change the language back after one letter?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am using the US Layout, but sometimes I need to write some umlauts (german letters). So my question is, is it possible to change the keyboard layout just for one letter, so it changes back to US Layout after that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing a full keyboard layout for just a single character is not implemented: you must change (you can use a hotkey for this) and then change back (again, that could be done with a hotkey. In Ubuntu, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> is configured to switch to the next keyboard layout, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to the previous.

So far about your *Y* problem. Now let's handle the *X* problem.

For typing single characters, there are **other and better options**.

*Option 1*: you can **switch to a keyboard variant** that supports entering international characters.

- The *English (US, intl., with dead keys)* keyboard layout turns some keys into dead keys. For example, hitting <kbd>"</kbd> alone will show nothing. A subsequent character, e.g. <kbd>u</kbd> will input a character with umlaut, "ü". (Slight) drawback here is that you need two key presses also to enter the character of the dead key, e.g. <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> or <kbd>"</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to enter ". For programmers, that may be more than a slight drawback.
- The *English (intl., with AltGr dead keys)* (thanks to KGIII to point this out) overcomes this drawback, but requires holding <kbd>AltGr</kbd> to activate the dead keys. <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is usually the right <kbd>Alt</kbd> key. Thus, umlaut is entered by holding <kbd>AltGr</kbd>, and then hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>"</kbd>. Hitting <kbd>U</kbd> then enters the ü.

These two keyboard layouts in addition make many characters directly available as combinations with <kbd>AltGr</kbd>. ü is directly available as <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, Í is obtained from <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, and so forth.

*Option 2*: you could use the **Linux "[Compose](https://fsymbols.com/keyboard/linux/compose/)" key feature**. With that system, you define one key, for example the left <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, to be the compose key. Pressing that key signals that following keyboard strokes should be interpreted to mean a character. Thus, hitting <kbd>Compose</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>"</kbd> or <kbd>Compose</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> would yield "ü". You can set a compose key using Gnome Tweaks, on the "Keyboard" tab.

(*Option 3*: Only relevant if you need to do this sporadically), load the **tool "Characters"** and copy the character from the tool to your clipboard. Characters you use frequently appear on the "Recently used" tab. So later on, you will quickly retrieve a character you use now and then.

Comment: There's also the US Intl with AltGr dead keys - which uses the AltGr (usually right alt key) and shift key as the modifier. So, the keyboard more or less functions as normal (no need to press the ' key twice or anything like that) until you press and hold the AltGr  key (as well as the shift key modifier). It's what I use/prefer because it eliminates the need to double-press the ' key and stuff like that.

Comment: @KGill, thanks, that sounds like a very usefull addition to the answer.

Comment: If you want to try it out, the name varies sometimes per distro. In Ubuntu, or at least Lubuntu, it's listed as "English (Intl., with AltGr dead keys)". If you'd like, I can add it as an Option 4 to your answer.

Comment: I already added it under Option 2. Thanks a lot! Indeed quite more convenient if you type " more frequently than ü!

Comment: You can actually just press AltGr and the Y and that types ü. It takes a bit to learn the layout, but I think it's worth it. You don't have to go through all the steps you listed to type ü or a ton of other characters. Just hold AltGr and press a letter. You can also hold AltGr and SHIFT and press letters.

Comment: This is in common with the "English (US, intl., with dead keys)". These two layouts mainly differ in how the dead keys are triggered. Actually, again very useful to mention in the answer

Comment: The Option 2 with the compose key works perfectly for me. Thanks for your answers.